# Ajax Mvc Submit Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i am new to ajax and i can't find a way to get passed my problem.

i have a view, on the left side there is a menu with ajax action links, 
which are updating the div on the right side with different partial views.

this views on the right side have submit buttons.

now my question, i don't wan't this button, each partial view should update or trigger the submit automatically, once the next menu click gets fired.

before i changed the menu to ajax.actionlinks i had done this by hooking the onbeforeunload event. but this event doesn't get fired with ajax updatetargetid.

here some code snippets:

index.cshtml

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    @Html.Partial("_Navigation")
</div>
<div id="LoadPageContainer" class="col-lg-9"></div>
```

_navigation.cshtml

```
 <li>
 @Ajax.ActionLink("one", "_one", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "LoadPageContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
  </li>
  <li>
  @Ajax.ActionLink("two", "_two", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "LoadPageContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
  </li>
```

Edit:
Adding the OnBegin AjaxOptions did the job for me.

Comment: You can use the `OnComplete` property for `AjaxOptions` to specify a javascript function. In that function you will trigger the submission.

Comment: the OnComplete triggers when i click for the new partialview, which doesn't help me at all, since i need to update the partialview, before  it get's replaced by the new one.